# Creating raw ISO image

Tags: image, iso, bootable

How can I create raw ISO Image ?

I mean I am programming simple system in assembler and I want to create an ISO which could put binary file (whole system is in one file) in BootSector.

Comment: Which operating system are you targeting? Your best option will probably be to use an external program to create the image.

Answer (score 1):

In good old DOS days I would have put such a thing on a disk. If this works for you you can use syslinux which is able to launch disk Images. Or even simpler: create bootable ISO with the disk Image set as boot Image.